# How to get str_replace to recognize umlauts in file names retrieved with glob (on a Mac)?

Tags: php, macos, ios, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm reading file names out of a directory with **glob** with the code below.

I want to iterate through them and replace umlaut characters with other characters.

However, `str_replace` does not even find the umlaut characters, so I assume they are in some other kind of character encoding.

This has always worked on Windows but I am now on a **Mac** so I tried to convert from "macintosh" to "UTF-8" with iconv but that didn't work, see below.

If I define a string with umlauts in code, *then* str_replace finds the umlauts fine but not in the strings retrieved with `glob()`.

**How can I get str_replace to recognize the umlaut characters in file name strings so I can replace them?**

```
$pathAndFileNames = glob($directory . '/*.php');
if (count($pathAndFileNames) > 0) {
    foreach ($pathAndFileNames as $oldName) {

        $newName = str_replace('ü', 'ue', $oldName);
        echo $newName; //outputs "rücktest.php"

        $oldName2 = "rücktest.php";
        $newName2 = str_replace('ü', 'ue', $oldName2);
        echo $newName2; //outputs "ruecktest.php"

    }
}
```

Comment: Try [mb_detect_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) to find out.

Comment: mb_detect_encoding tells me it is UTF-8, so why can't str_replace find an umlaut in a UTF-8 string?

Comment: mb_detect_encoding($oldName, 'UTF-8', true) returns true

Comment: I checked both the code file and the file that is being read in with glob() and both are UTF-8, no BOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this code on my machine (Ubuntu mind you) and had no such issue. I have one solution for you to try. Make sure your script is saved with UTF-8 encoding.

I can replicate your issue when saving the file with Western-8859-15 encoding, but when the file is saved with UTF-8 encoding the script behaves as you would expect.

Check your editor preferences and save as functionality.

Comment: thanks, I cleaned up the code, which still doesn't work: it converts the umlaut in the text that I define in code, but not the file name text, why is it not finding the umlaut if everything is UTF-8?